# Spring Boot CXF with file attachement

Tags: java, spring-boot, cxf

I would like to send attachements trougth CXF in Java Spring boot app.

I used : cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws (3.2.2), cxf-rt-databinding-xmlbeans(2.7.18), spring boot(1.5.10.RELEASE) : acttully i managed those dependencies version in order to get the app started perfectly.

I exposed my service as with one method that attach a file  in the WebServiceContext of javax.xml.ws with its property "javax.xml.ws.binding.attachments.outbound"

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT, use = SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL, parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
@DataBinding(value = XmlBeansDataBinding.class)
@MTOM(enabled=true)
```

All is loaded and the service start, only that i cannot find the attachement when i invicke my service with another client app.

Is there any idea that guide me to solve this serious problem?

Comment: You are mixing different CXF version (3.2.2 and 2.7.18). I suggest to clean it up first.

Comment: What do you mean with cannot finding the attachment?

Comment: @Dennis, actually when  i tried to request the service with SOAP UI and even with a java client, the attachement doesn't  existe in the response